# Failed to pull image from private registry with Authentication required error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, kubernetes-pod

I have set up a private docker registry with self-signed certificates.

```
docker run -d -p 443:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v `pwd`/auth:/auth 
-e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm"
-e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd -v `pwd`/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/domain.crt 
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/domain.key
```

domain.crt and domain.key are generated using OpenSSL.

To Connect from a remote host,

```
cp domain.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/mydockerregistry.com.crt
update-ca-trust
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

After this able to log in from the remote host

```
docker login mydockerregistry.com --username=test
password: test
```

I am able to push/pull the image to this registry and it is successful.

Similarly, I tried to deploy this image in the Kubernetes cluster. I created a secret with the registry with a username and password.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry my-registry --docker-server=mydockerregistry.com --docker-username=test --docker-password=test --docker-email=abc.com
```

Also, I did the self-signed certificates from docker registry steps in worker nodes,

```
cp domain.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/mydockerregistry.com.crt
update-ca-trust
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Given the name in the imagePullSecrets of deployment.yaml file. I am trying to create a POD in the Kubernetes cluster (Calico Network) but it is unable to pull the image.

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-image
  labels:
    app: test-image
    chart: test-image
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      image: "mydockerregistry.com/test-image:latest"
      imagePullPolicy: Always
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: my-registry
```

> Warning  Failed          45s (x2 over 59s)  kubelet,
>   kube-worker-02  **Failed to pull image
>   "mydockerregistry.com/test-image:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown
>   desc = unauthorized: authentication required**
>   Warning  Failed
>   45s (x2 over 59s)  kubelet, kube-worker-02  **Error: ErrImagePull**

I checked the docker registry logs,

> time="2020-01-13T14:58:05.269921112Z" **level=error msg="error
>   authenticating user "": authentication failure" go.version=go1.11.2
>   http.request.host=mydockerregistry.com**
>   http.request.id=02fcccff-9a30-443c-8a00-48bcacb90e99
>   http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="10.76.112.148:35454"
>   http.request.uri="/v2/test-image/manifests/latest"
>   http.request.useragent="docker/1.13.1 go/go1.10.8
>   kernel/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64
>   UpstreamClient(Go-http-client/1.1)" vars.name=test-image
>   vars.reference=latest
>
> time="2020-01-13T14:58:05.269987492Z" **level=warning msg="error
>   authorizing context: basic authentication challenge for realm
>   "Registry Realm": authentication failure" go.version=go1.11.2
>   http.request.host=mydockerregistry.com**
>   http.request.id=02fcccff-9a30-443c-8a00-48bcacb90e99
>   http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="10.76.112.148:35454"
>   http.request.uri="/v2/ca-config-calc/manifests/latest"
>   http.request.useragent="docker/1.13.1 go/go1.10.8
>   kernel/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64
>   UpstreamClient(Go-http-client/1.1)" vars.name=test-image
>   vars.reference=latest

I am able to do docker login myregistrydomain and pull the image from worker node

Anything I am missing in the configuration?

Comment: Share your deployment.yaml where you have configured `imagePullSecret`.

Comment: added the deployment YAML file

Comment: I think it has something to do with registry-server name. Can you share the output of `cat ~/.docker/config.json` on the system where you have manually logged in.

Comment: `~/.docker/config.json` below `{
        "auths": {
                "mydockerregistry.com": {
                        "auth": "YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
                }
        }
}
`

Comment: @Gopi, Try to specify you registry url using https: `https://mydockerregistry.com`. Let me know if it works

Comment: @Gopi, Any update ?

Comment: @rabello Sorry for no response. Actually while debugging the registry container logs, I found that the username is going as empty in the request. `error authenticating user ""` . Then I deleted the secret and created a new secret using yaml file. Not really sure what was a mistake I have done while creating in cmd line. After that, it worked.

Comment: @Gopi, Do you need any help about your question or it solved completely you problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the registry name in the create secret command.

`kubectl create secret docker-registry my-registry --docker-server=myregistryregistry.com --docker-username=test --docker-password=test --docker-email=abc.com`

Change `myregistryregistry.com` to `mydockerregistry.com` which you have used with `docker login`.

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo in the question. I have used correct name `mydockerregistry.com` only.

Comment: note : if you have a $ in your password, you must escape it by using \$

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to successfully pull an image from a secure, private, docker registry into kubernetes using [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).